# Extracting Grammar Rules from Brown Corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a file of parenthetical trees from the Brown corpus, which looks like this:

```
(TOP (S (NP (NNP Ambassador)
            (NNP Stevenson))
        (NP (RB yesterday))
        (VP (VBD described)
            (NP (NP (DT the)
                    (NNP U.N.))
                (POS 's)
                (NN problem)
                (PP (IN of)
                    (S (NP (-NONE- *))
                       (VP (VBG electing)
                           (NP (DT a)
                               (ADJP (JJ temporary))
                               (NN successor)
                               (PP (TO to)
                                   (NP (DT the)
                                       (ADJP (JJ late))
                                       (NP (NNP Dag)
                                           (NNP Hammarskjold)))))))))
            (PP (IN as)
                (`` ``)
                (NP (NP (DT the)
                        (ADJP (JJS gravest))
                        (NN crisis))
                    (SBAR (-NONE- 0)
                          (S (NP (DT the)
                                 (NN institution))
                             (AUX (VBZ has))
                             (VP (VBN faced)
```

I have to extract all grammar rules from this file, in the form:

```
S -> NP VP
NP -> DT NNS
VP -> VBD NP
NP -> NN
```

etc.

I'm trying to read in the parenthetical tree as a tree in nltk, but I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\tree.py", line 666, in fromstring cls._parse_error(s, match, 'end-of-string')
```

File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\nltk\tree.py", line 734, in _parse_error
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Tree.read(): expected 'end-of-string' but got '(TOP'
at index 24.
"...XT_UNIT)  (TOP (S (N..."

I want to use productions from nltk, but can't get this file to be read as an nltk tree. Please help!

Comment: Also this is the end of the error:ValueError: Tree.read(): expected 'end-of-string' but got '(TOP'
            at index 24.
                "...XT_UNIT)  (TOP (S (N..."

Comment: Are you sure that's the full sentence/example? There are definitely parentheses missing at the end, which would cause a parsing error. It would also be better if you provide a minimal code snippet to show what you have tried so far.